# Anatomy of an .svn folder

Tags: svn, version-control

While trying to commit a change with svn I got `svn: Illegal repository URL ''` error. Later found out that `URL` and `Repository Root` starts with `file://` when I do `svn info`. I was told to edit the `.svn/entries` and update the `URL` and `Repository Root` with the correct paths.

I have been using svn for sometime but never had a need to get into .svn directory to do anything except the above problem. Could someone explain what is each file/folder for inside .svn and when it is needed to hack into these to fix something?

- entries
- prop-base
- props
- text-base
- tmp

Answer (score 2):

You should never edit the contents of `.svn` directly unless you know exactly what you're doing and why. It should only be touched via the Subversion client libraries.

Editing the contents of `.svn` directly may get the desired results. Or it may break your working copy completely.

To change where your repository points, you should use `svn switch` to point to a different path within the same repository, and `svn relocate` (or `svn switch --relocate` in versions that haven't implemented the alias yet) to point to the same repository path on a different host/protocol.

You can't, to my knowledge, change both the host/protocol *and* the path inside the repository. For that, you'll need to check out a new working copy and migrate any changes over to it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and good to know about svn switch and svn relocate. But I am more interested in the .svn folder structure. Even if it is not advised to mess with them what are they used for.

Comment: The `.svn` directory contains all the metadata about the working copy, including pristine copies of all the files (so you can perform local diffs), the properties of the files, and references to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'svn help switch', used to switch a working copy to a new URL.  Be sure to read the bits on '--ignore-ancestry' and '--relocate' (which switches from file:// to http://, apparently).

And, as a safety thing, you might copy the working copy to a different directory so that there's no chance of any changes being lost.

That way, at the very worst, you *could* check out a new working copy and then copy your changes over.

Also, I'm on svn 1.7.5.  You didn't mention your version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and good to know about svn switch and svn relocate. But I am more interested in the .svn folder structure. Even if it is not advised to mess with them what are they used for.